# Globally prevent text selection in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using:

```
*{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Go to http://jsfiddle.net/KyF5x/ and click below the list, see that this highlights the text... which can't be un-highlighted. Reload the page, now try ctrl+a, see that this will also highlight the text.

The above doesn't occur in Chrome, Safari or IE 10.

Disclaimer: I'm using Firefox 18

Comment: Applying the CSS to the individual <li> elements fixes this issue... However i'd still be interested to see a way of fixing this issue document-wide.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to do this? Just wondering. It'd probably just make your site a bit annoying to use, I'd think.

Comment: It's for a web app which I'm creating. Which has draggable content, to overcome it i've creared a .Unselectable css class and i'm applying it to the menu items and draggable content.

Comment: It sure gets tiresome seeing someone ask a specific question and then get their motives questioned, harassed and/or judged because others think it's foolish/foolhardy/stupid/[fill-in-the-blank]. It's none of our business and is beside the point to interject hyperbole, scorn and schadenfreude into often otherwise straight-forward questions. I've been guilty too. But I'm trying. /`EndOfRant` Jack, you should post and accept that as the answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: If JS is in the question, you could always use `onselectstart = function() {return: false;}`

Comment: @Mooseman I've tried, and it doesn't seem to solve the issue. Atleast not on a document wide level http://jsfiddle.net/KyF5x/2/ please say if i'm missing something in the jsfiddle link in this comment.

Comment: @Jack Nothing is selectable here.

Comment: @Mooseman In Firefox click below the list of items, it will highlight them.

Comment: @Jack Yes, I see that in FF18. I fixed it in http://jsfiddle.net/KyF5x/3/. FF is selecting the `<ul>`, not each `<li>`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish If I had not asked that question I would never have guessed a positive use of disabling text highlighting. Its like all those sites who prevent you from right clicking and viewing the page source and then you have to use the view menu of your browser and click view source. I'll also try and refrain from judging, my personal initial opinion of the idea is indeed not useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a temporary answer, the fix is the apply the CSS to the individual 'unselectable' elements. However i'd love to see someone come up with a document-wide fix.

```
li{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/KyF5x/1/

A use case for having document-wide unselectable text is more obvious in the domain of web apps, rather than typical websites.

Comment: Sure, there's a way to do it document-wide... http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/LP2PQ/

Comment: Here it is as just a page (little easier to navigate): http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/LP2PQ/1/show/ At least in FF18, Chrome latest, I can't select anything, and I've got more or less all of the elements represented. Even `input` text. Which is strange.

Comment: Of course, in IE9 and lower and Chrome 12.12, it's hosed. Wonder what's going on with that `-ms-user-select: none;`.

Comment: And [`body > *`](http://jsfiddle.net/KyF5x/5/) works in Chrome latest and Firefox 18. Probably a little more reasonable than the CSS reset method. See it here too: http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/LP2PQ/2/show/

Comment: None of the above seems to work in Firefox 20. I can select the page content with ctrl-a in every of these examples. Any idea of how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to Jack's answer - even in 2018, firefox does not support user-select, but does support moz-user-select. I chose a cut down version of what the fiddle in the accepted answer does:

```
/* stop the user selecting page structure with the mouse */
html, body, div, a, i, button, select, option, optgroup, hr, br {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

This is for a web app where we don't use any other elements, all page structures are divs, even titles etc, and we didn't want to disallow selection in input or textarea.

This was the only place in our entire web 500k lines of code app where we've had to use -moz- !!