# Prevent selection in Firefox in CSS

Tags: css, firefox, selection

I want to disallow element selection using only CSS (selection either with the mouse or with CRTL+A). I tried the following:

```
element {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

element::-moz-selection {
    background: transparent;
}
```

and it does not work correctly in Firefox 20. It works in webkit though. I am able to select images and canvas with CTRL+A even with the above CSS rules.

Is there a way, using CSS only (without JS), to disallow the selection (or at least not show it).

I don't want to stop the user from copying text, I just want to hide the selection on some elements.

I tried the codes in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307593/globally-prevent-text-selection-in-firefox/14307806#answer-14307806), but it does not seem to work in Firefox 20.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it in FF20 with the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADGsA/

```
p.noselect { -moz-user-select:none; }
p.recolor::-moz-selection { color: yellow;  background: red; }
```

All behaviours with mouse are as expected, but I can indeed select the text with ctrl-A still. I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Gecko, but it's also quite possibly not one they're going to solve, judging by [the MDN reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/user-select):

> Note: user-select is not currently part of any W3C CSS specification. 
>   As such, there are minor differences between the browser
>   implementations. Be sure to test your application across browsers.

Non-standardized, so unpredictable. Take what you get and be lucky with it I guess, you might consider raising a bug on Bugzilla for it since I really think they didn't intend this, as the mentioned page also says:

> Controls the appearance (only) of selection.

That would indicate that ctrl-A also should not be able to select it.

---

EDIT:

It's been a [known issue since November 2008](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=463765). Don't hold your breath for a fix, upvote it and pray.